# Unable to mount /dev/sda6 - Authentication required on Fedora 23

Tags: fedora, fedora-23

When I try to open /dev/sda6 I am getting the following error in the `Authentication Required` screen,

```
Incorrect permissions on /usr/lib/po1kit-agent-helper-1(needs to be setuid root)
```

Comment: What do you get with `ls -l /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1`? This file _should_ be setuid root. Was this working before? Might something have happened which got you into this situation?

Comment: It was working before now I am getting the following output `-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 15352 Jul 15  2015 /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1
`

Comment: More over now I am unable to save any of my screenshots to `pictures` directory directly, I am getting unable to create file error

Comment: Okay, that is very concerning, as that shows that the polkit executable is marked _world writeable_. That can't happen by accident.

Comment: I am very new to fedora (Linux), You have any idea on how to resolve this

Comment: You can resolve the immediate permissions problem by running `sudo rpm -f /usr/lib/polkit-1/polkit-agent-helper-1 --setperms`. But I think it's very likely that that's only a symptom of a deeper problem. Have you logged in as `root`? Have you run any commands with `sudo`? Do you know what those commands did?

Comment: Also, are you sure about that error message? Please directly copy and paste rather than re-typing. I say this because it seems unlikely that it's actually saying `po1kit-agent` rather than `polkit-agent`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110583/discussion-between-bachan-and-mattdm).